# How can I put a timer or wait when sending http requests in c#?

Tags: c#, timer, wait, sleep, throttling

I am to send over 1 million request to an api programatically. Looks like every 200 requests I get throttled and need to wait 5 min before sending another 200. How can I do this through c# code? I've looked at timers, but I'm confused how the logic works. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just use ```System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000);``` every 200 calls. It will let your thread be suspended and wait 5min before doing the next statement. But you wanna send 1M requests and you want to wait 5min every 200 requests. So you will wait 5min 5000 times = 25 000 min = 416 hours = 17 days !!!! Are you sure you want to do this ?

Comment: 200 requests every 5 minutes means you'll have to run this continually for 17+ days to complete all 1 million requests.

Comment: @RonBeyer I hope it's not a traffic info app :D

Comment: @OlivierDepriester Or something that the user needs to load record # 986,594 for...

Answer (score 0):

As Ron Beyer pointed out, the math is not in your favor. If you get throtheled every 200 requests, it will take 5000 cycles to complete all 1 million of them. Wich equals at least 25000 minutes, or 416 hours, or 17.36 days. And that is the *minimum* time, asuming the requests themself do not take any time.

I guess it is save to say, the API provider **does not want you to do that**. While you can throttle your requests to match, it will not mater as *17 days* is propably a bit long for any application. You would need a database table just to store the total amount of requests and how far you managed to process those 1 million requests.

The only way to do this, would be if there is a API call that allows bulk requests. With Networking overhead, it is clear that 1 request for 200 items will not take as long as 200 requests for 1 item each. But for that, you have to talk with the API provider.

Comment: I'm guessing that any throttled API also has a (paid) non-throttled API that the OP could use to get this data faster, they are just trying to do it outside the terms of the "free" API.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @MikeH "It is 95% impossible with the stated figures" is not a valid answer?

Comment: @MikeH How many processes do you know that have **over two weeks** as acceptable runtime? And I do not mean servers, but an actuall, single operation.

Comment: @Christopher My position is that this is "not an answer".  It's perfect for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reactive Extensions TimeShifting Sequences to achieve this. You can view the examples [here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html)

If you want your own implementation you can view this:

https://codeburst.io/throttling-concurrent-outgoing-http-requests-in-net-core-404b5acd987b